# Using passport-twitter node module, can I reduce the default permissions I'm requesting from the user for authentication?

Tags: passport.js, passport-twitter

I'm using passport-twitter for authentication. When the user is directed to the login page, it says my app will be able to do the following.

[image]

Many of those permissions may scare away users. I don't want to update their profile, post tweets for them, access their direct messages or read their tweets. (I may want to see who they follow in the future but not needed now).

Can I reduce the permissions somehow?

I am also using the passport-reddit node module and I am able to control the scope/permissions that my app asks for. Wondering how this can be done using passport-twitter.

Comment: Aren't you able to specify scope like this: `passport.authenticate('twitter', { scope: ['tweets', ...] }),`? I'm not sure but that seems to be the default way for all or most other strategies

Comment: That's the first thing I tried but it kept requesting the same permissions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering my own question as an Answer rather than comment so I can post some images.

The short answer is that for this particular network, you cannot configure the permissions through the passport module and API. Instead, it's all maintained in your App Management on Twitter.

So you'll want to go to your App and click on the Permissions tab like the one shown here
[image]

By default, I believe the Access level is "Read Only" but I think I changed it when I was testing out direct messaging.
This is the page that maintains all your twitter app permissions, not the passport module. This differs from other networks, like Facebook, where you can provide the scope parameter to the passport-facebook module.

Here's what the user should see when they log in with "Read only" permissions for your app
[image]

Sorry for any confusion. But hopefully, this helps others who are trying to figure out how to change their permissions, and they're coming from the background of using other passport modules that let you do it from the API